# Getting a form post checkbox variable from a mysql database outside a while loop on another page

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have read through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10759218/php-getting-variables-outside-while-loop) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361618/checkbox-in-a-while-loop) post, which looks to be the most similar, but it has not solved my problem.

I have the below while loop working to display results from my database. The specific line of question in the while loop is this (note: it is within a form):

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
<input type='checkbox' name='check_box_delete[]' value='".$row['BookingNo']."'>
}
```

The rest of the form data passes through fine except for the checkboxes. In the following php page, I have this:

```
if(isset($_POST['check_box_delete'])){
    foreach($_POST['check_box_delete'] as $id){
        $sql="DELETE FROM bookings WHERE BookingNo='".$id."'";
        if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
            die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
        }
    echo $id." deleted.";
}
```

The page echos `deleted` but no associated $id. I suspect my processor.php is not getting the booking number at all.

Answer (score 0):

When it says "Record successfully deleted" it only means that there are some checkboxes have been checked.

Use `mysqli_affected_rows()` function to determine if you deleted something. It will show you the situation.

Comment: The "Record successfully deleted" means that the code is going to the right spot (I've edited OP for clarification) sorry.
I've added
    echo mysqli_affected_rows()
under the echo "Record..." but nothing is printing

Answer (score 0):

Change `num` to `$num` in your delete query and try again.

```
$sql="DELETE FROM bookings WHERE BookingNo=".num; //here should be $num
```

Comment: Wow I can't believe I missed that; thanks. Fixed but still not working sorry.

Comment: Try changing your query to this "DELETE FROM `bookings` WHERE BookingNo='$num'"; (Put backtick in table name) And `Record successfully deleted` will be always displayed because you are just echoing it without checking if the record is actually deleted or not.

Comment: Do you mean this:

         else{
   $sql="DELETE FROM bookings WHERE BookingNo='$num'";
   $result=mysqli_query($sql);
  }
That's what I now have but still nothing

Comment: What i meant was to wrap your table name with backticks (`).

Comment: Right, nope, still nothing sorry. The query is working fine, I'm sure, the problem lies with getting the correct $booking id from the form

Comment: Hope you found the solution. I noticed that you also missed `$` here `if (!result){`

Comment: Nope, still not working. I'm going to look at it with fresh eyes tomorrow which will hopefully make a difference. Thanks for your help though

Comment: I've updated the OP with what it looks like now. I tried to cut away anything extra that I didn't need