# Get a form post checkbox variable from a mysql database outside a while loop on another page

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

I have previously submitted this question but it was not resolved. I have worked on other parts of the site I'm trying to build and I have come back to this issue again. Below is the OP; [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19085896/getting-a-form-post-checkbox-variable-from-a-mysql-database-outside-a-while-loop) is the previous question.

I have read through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10759218/php-getting-variables-outside-while-loop) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361618/checkbox-in-a-while-loop) post, which looks to be the most similar, but it has not solved my problem.

I have the below while loop working to display results from my database. The specific line of question in the while loop is this (note: it is within a form):

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
<input type='checkbox' name='check_box_delete[]' value='".$row['BookingNo']."'>
}
```

The rest of the form data passes through fine except for the checkboxes. In the following php page, I have this:

```
if(isset($_POST['check_box_delete'])){
    foreach($_POST['check_box_delete'] as $id){
        $sql="DELETE FROM bookings WHERE BookingNo='".$id."'";
        if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
            die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
        }
    echo $id." deleted.";
}
```

The page echos `deleted` but no associated $id. I suspect my processor.php is not getting the booking number at all.

Cheers

Comment: What do you see if you View Source in the browser. Are the values there in the checkboxes?

Comment: var_dump($_POST['check_box_delete']);

Comment: @Barmar, thank you. I feel exceptionally silly, but after viewing the source code I noticed the checkbox field was empty. My MySQL query wasn't getting the BookingNo as so not passing it onto the checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

The page your form sends to seems alright except for the fact that $id is outside the loop. The following works for me.

```
<form action = "process.php" method = "POST">

<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "dbname");

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$query = "SELECT * FROM tablename";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "<input type='checkbox' name='check_box_delete[]' value='".$row['BookingNo']."'>";
}

?>

<input type = "submit">

</form>
```

And then proccess.php

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['check_box_delete'])){
    foreach($_POST['check_box_delete'] as $id){
        $sql="DELETE FROM bookings WHERE BookingNo='".$id."'";
        if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
            die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
        }
        echo $id." deleted.<br>";
    }
}

?>
```